# default 'post' post type: not forcing url rewrite when args set

Tags: rewrite-rules

I'm trying to update the default 'post' post type's permalink structure to `site.com/articles/{post-title}` (programmatically, *not* using the settings menu)

I'm using the `register_post_type_args` filter to update the post type arguments:

```
add_filter('register_post_type_args', [ $this, 'update_post_type_labels' ], 10, 2 );

public function update_post_type_labels( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type !== 'post' ) {
        return $args;
    }

    $args['rewrite'] = array(
        'slug' => 'articles',
        'with_front' => true
    );

    return $args;
}
```

It seems to be only half working, as after I flush the rewrite rules, the post still defaults to `site.com/{post-name}`, however I can also access it at `site.com/articles/{post-name}`. If I remove the filter and flush again, `site.com/articles/{post-name}` redirects to `site.com/{post-name}`.

***Why isn't WordPress forcing the rewrite?***

Comment: Without doing any investigation, I'll guess that the `post` post type is a special case due to the fact that it normally gets its structure from the `permalink_structure` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permalink structure for `post` by updating the option that stores it:

```
update_option( 'permalink_structure', '/articles/%postname%/' );
```